# Почему в режиме hover двигается иконка Font Awesome?

Tags: html, css

Есть один вопрос.
Почему в режиме :hover двигается иконка Font Awesome?
Верстка на bootstrap 4.
Кусок кода:

```css
(CSS):
В hover-е написал только:
#carouselExampleReviews a:hover {
    background: rgba(106, 15, 90, .43);
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
(HTML):
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleReviews" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-cl-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <i class="far fa-angle-left"></i>
    </span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleReviews" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-cl-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <i class="far fa-angle-right"></i>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Сделайте простой пример где она двигается, чтобы тут его можно было запустить. Так больше шанс что вас поймут и ответят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю это происходит из-за `border: 0;`, под бордер выделено место и когда вы его убираете, иконка сдвигается. Попробуйте не убрать бордер а поменять его цвет на тот, что в ховере или прописать transparented

Comment: Добрый вечер! Удалил border: 0; и добавил border-color: transparent; . В итоге получилась. Спасибо Денис!!!

Comment: @G__FE, Если ответ Вам помог, поставьте галочку рядом с ответом!